# How to implement a reusable navigation menu in bootstrap/html

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to implement a reusable navigation menu for my bootstrap/html web site. It has several pages and I dont want to copy/paste code. How can a implement a reusable navigation menu in bootstrap/html?

Answer (score -1):

In ASP.Net MVC with Razor you could put your common navigation markup in the _Layout.cshtml view.  I guess other languages/environments have similar features.